# What is most popular ajax framework for modern days?

Tags: javascript, ajax

If I'm developing a client side application with heavy load, what is the most appropriate choice of Ajax framework?

Comment: What exactly is an "Ajax framework"? The term has turned into such a buzzword that it's pretty vague on its own. What specifically are you looking for?

Comment: It must be something like which javascript library is popular to carry out asynchronous calls to the server. jQuery is popular. (node.js is popular on the server which is different of course. Just saying).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend you the [JQuery](http://jquery.com/). It is not just an ajax framework, it is more than that.

Comment: Yes, Approximately all frameworks (Primefaces, Richfaces etc) is build on JQUERY

Comment: Not exactly a framework, but it's used to build client-side frameworks, and feature-wise, it does just about everything you'll ever need it to. The OP wasn't really clear on what he/she wanted, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Client side? [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). Server side? Depends on your environment. Also, AJAX is not a framework per definition, but there are various libraries like jQuery which will ease the pain when using AJAX.

AJAX exists just to send some data and recieve some data from your server or some other site without forcing you to do a whole page reload. That's all about it in the nutshell.

If you're looking for a technology that will automatically place widgets on your site that use AJAX, that's a whole different story...